# How to automatically refresh the GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm newbie to Tkinter i want to help please

This my first App:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk() 
root = Button( text ="Hello",activeforeground="red")
root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm using Vscode on linux mint and i wanna try some options of different widget without close and reopen the window each time i make changes (I want just something like **Live Server** for web pages )

Comment: If the script file is modified, the application must be restarted to make the changes effective.

Comment: Okay @acw1668 !Can i build a simple IDE using this library because i have already build a compiler and i want build an UI using that library ,Can i do that with Tkinter or i should switch to another one ?

Comment: Why do you want to build a new IDE if you are using Vscode which is already an IDE?

Comment: @acw1668 Yeah i knew but i wanna build mine so without execut command from terminal (bison and flex command and build the exection file ) i would like to build a simple user interface that make life much easier ... just contain a text area where we can put the source code that we wanna execute and two buttons 'Build and compile' and 'Run'

Comment: Then `tkinter` and `subprocess` may be enough.

Comment: Thanks you so much @acw1668 !